# Remove cookies with name + guid in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a webshop where the cart items are stored in a cookie. This cookie gets name "cart_xxx" where the xxx is dynamic. I need to remove this cookie, but since the name varies i cant just use name. Maybe there is a way in c# to filter after cookies that starts with "cart"

anyone have an idea?

Comment: I think Cookies are Key,Pair You should know the name of key or You can clear All Cookies

Comment: [`HttpCookieCollection.AllKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.allkeys.aspx) returns a `string[]` which you can filter, unlike the `Keys` property which returns a specialized collection. Have you considered storing all carts in a single cookie?